# Autenticação ASP NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autenticação, permissões

Qual melhor forma de se fazer a separação de permissões para usuários logados? Seria usando anotações e roles? Porque quero liberar certas paginas e certas funções dependendo da permissão do usuário logado.

Alguém poderia me informar melhor como poderia ser feito e se tem algum exemplo.

A tabela de permissão que tenho no banco de dados é uma tabela com um ID e um Nome somente, ai na tabela de usuário tem um campo que fica com o nome das permissões separadas por virgula.

Comment: Você está usando o MVC5?

Comment: Isso, estou utilizando o mvc 5, e já tenho uma tabela no oracle com as permissões, gostaria de usar ela.

Comment: Pode editar sua pergunta e colocar como é sua tabela?

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Comment: É uma péssima abordagem a da tabela de usuários. Deveria ser uma tabela associativa entre usuários e permissões. É possível mudar isso?

Comment: Eu já peguei o sistema assim, mas posso mudar sim, queria ter uma ideia de como pode ser feito no asp net mvc, dai eu mudo o banco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente, escrevendo seu próprio atributo de autorização. Por exemplo:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class MeuAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private String[] _permissoes;
    private MeuProjetoContext contexto = new MeuProjetoContext();

    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(params String[] permissoes) 
    {
        _permissoes = permissoes;
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var baseReturn = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);

        var permissoesReturn = false;
        var permissoesUsuario = contexto.Permissoes.Where(p => p.Usuario.Nome == httpContext.User.Identity.Name).Select(p => NomePermissao).ToList();
        permissoesReturn = permissoesUsuario.Intersect(_permissoes.OfType<String>().ToList()).Any();

        return permissionsReturn || baseReturn;
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
[MeuAuthorize("Usuário", "Gerente", "Administrador")]
public ActionResult MinhaAction() { ... }
```

Pode ser usado sem parâmetros, apenas para verificar se está logado:

```
[MeuAuthorize]
public ActionResult MinhaAction() { ... }
```

Comment: Me ajudou bastante, outra duvida, tem como eu usar essa autorização que você passou para um trecho de código somente? por exemplo, em uma pagina eu tenho 2 forms, cada um aparece dependendo da permissão?

Comment: @HenriqueDomingosPereira Sim. Abra outra pergunta que te explico em detalhes.

Comment: criei http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77612/asp-net-mvc-permiss%C3%A3o-por-bloco

Comment: essa classe `MeuAuthorize`, onde vc recomenta que eu crie ela, estou usando DDD, e eu tenho que dar um `using` sempre que for usa la?

Comment: DDD é uma péssima abordagem pra MVC. De qualquer forma, se você possui um diretório para infraestrutura, coloque abaixo dele um outro diretório chamado `Attributes`.

Comment: Blza, e tem alguma forma de deixar ele global, ou sempre tenho q chama-lo no arquivo que for utilizar?

Comment: Tem sim. Abra outra pergunta que explico como fazer.

Comment: Abri http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77628/autentica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-asp-net-mvc-estendendo-authorizeattribute

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26470/discussion-between-henrique-domingos-pereira-and-cigano-morrison-mendez).