# Asp Net MVC Permissão por bloco

Tags: asp.net-mvc, permissões

Estou separando as permissões em minha aplicação, estou usando uma autorização customizado com a classe Authorize, já consigo separar permissão por action e controller, gostaria de saber como uso apenas para trechos de código, por exemplo, em uma pagina eu tenho 2 forms, cada um aparece dependendo da permissão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assim, na *View*:

```cs
@if (User.IsInRole("Role1")) 
{
    @* Escreva o form aqui *@
} else if (User.IsInRole("Role2")) 
{
    @* Escreva outro form aqui *@
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Esqueci de um detalhe importante: É preciso customizar também o `UserManager` para buscar a *Role* de uma maneira customizada:

## `App_Start/IdentityConfig.cs`

```cs
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    ...

    public override async Task<bool> IsInRoleAsync(string userId, string role)
    {
        // Coloque aqui sua regra de negócio para pesquisa de Roles.
        // return await base.IsInRoleAsync(userId, role);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Esse `User` já pega o usuário logado, ou tenho que passar ele pra view?

Comment: Já pega o usuário logado. Ele é preenchido automaticamente pelo *Controller*.

Comment: Criei uma autorização customizada `[MinhaAuth("TL001","TL002")]` e to tentando o `@if (User.IsInRole("TL002")){}` mas não está indo, tem algo a mais para fazer?

Comment: @HenriqueDomingosPereira Vou ter que expandir a resposta para customizar o `RoleManager`. Apenas estou procurando as referências e já completo a resposta.

Comment: @HenriqueDomingosPereira `RoleManager` não. `UserManager`. Editei a resposta.