# Autenticação Asp Net MVC estendendo AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autenticação, permissões

Estou fazendo autenticação estendendo AuthorizeAttribute, tenho duas duvidas, na minha aplicação DDD, eu vou criar essa classe na DAL? E como eu deixo essa classe global para usar em todos os controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estou supondo que você irá usar C# na solução.

Modifique o seguinte no arquivo `Global.asax.cs`:

```cs
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new MeuAuthorizeAttribute()); // Aqui
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

Com isto, todos os *Controllers* e suas respectivas *Actions* passarão pelo seu *Authorize* customizado.